# Network traffic to github.com is incredibly slow lately

Tags: networking, 16.04, chromium, github

Since about a week ago, any network traffic to/from github.com on one computer has been exceedingly slow. Any webpage request and any pull/push/fetch from any github repo typically takes 3-5 minutes before eventually loading. Other computers on the same network (one running the same distro of ubuntu) have no trouble with these tasks. Loading of other webpages on the same computer are very fast. I've tried browsing github.com using chromium and firefox on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. pinging github.com sometimes results in 100% packet loss after many minutes or rarely receives response packets with small latency as I would expect it to.

The network I refer to is at an educational institution with Gigabit speed and the computer in question does not have a local firewall enabled.

Does anybody have any insight?

EDIT (results from @GraysonKent's suggestion):

```
wget -O /dev/null --report-speed=bits https://github.com
--2017-03-21 13:55:45--  https://github.com/
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.113, 192.30.253.112
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.113|:443... failed:  Connection timed out.
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.112|:443...connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

/dev/null [ <=> ]  90.95K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

2017-03-21 13:57:52 (5.49 Mb/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [93136]
```

Running wget for 192.30.253.112 directly results in:

```
wget -O /dev/null --report-speed=bits 192.30.253.112
--2017-03-21 13:58:23--  http://192.30.253.112/
Connecting to 192.30.253.112:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://192.30.253.112/ [following]
--2017-03-21 13:58:25--  https://192.30.253.112/
Connecting to 192.30.253.112:443... connected.
    ERROR: certificate common name ‘github.com’ doesn't match requested host name ‘192.30.253.112’.
To connect to 192.30.253.112 insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Comment: Are you running a proxy by chance?

Comment: No proxy. I tried adding the google DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) before the institution default DNS servers and there's no change. I added the line `192.30.253.112 github.com` to my /etc/hosts file and this seems to be a hackish way to resolve the ip resolution problem. All web requests to the domain github.com seem to resolve to the desired 112 address and browsing and pull/push/fetch operations are consistently fast. I'd like to understand the root of the problem but I think this is an adequate temporary fix.

Comment: @RyanNeph Did you fix it? i have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You covered all the normal things I could think of. Here is what I would try next:

### Test for Network issues:

Run

```
wget -O /dev/null --report-speed=bits https://github.com
```

on a few computers in the lab and change out the url for the project you are testing.

If that doesn't yield anything, maybe try:

```
ping -c3 github.com
```

And note if the route is different.

### Test for Git issues:

Run the following with your normal git commands:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1
```

Beyond that, can you re-image this machine?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried them and it seems that for either the wget or ping command issued against github.com the ip address is either resolved to 192.30.253.112 or *.*.*.113. When resolved to *.*.*.112 the ping command returns 100% packet received while *.*.*.113 returns no packets received.  I've updated the original question to show these results. Is this a problem with my certificate for the https connection?